# Vue.js method undefined in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I am trying to pass a click method as a prop to my component's child's child. However, it seems like it works fine if the method doesn't take any parameters. However, if it takes parameters, Vue.js sends me a `Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined` error.

Here's my top-level component:

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function () {
    },
    methods: {
      action1: function () {
        console.log('--action 1--')
      },
      action2: function (word) {
        console.log('--action 2--', word)
      }
    }
  });
```

Here's my child component:

```
  Vue.component('parent-component', {
    template: '#parent-component',
    data () {
      return {
        menuItems: [
          {
            label: 'Action 1',
            onClick : this.action1
          },
          {
            label: 'Action 2',
            onClick : this.action2('two')
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    props: ['action1', 'action2']
  });

  <template id="parent-component">
    <action-menu :actions="menuItems"></action-menu>
  </template>
```

And here is my lowest level component:

```
  Vue.component('action-menu', {
    template: '#action-menu',
    props: ['actions'],
  });

<template id="action-menu">
  <div>
    <div v-for="action in actions">
      <button @click="action.onClick">{{ action.label }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/11sfg1p8/ - notice how the first button works, but the second button doesn't and the only difference is the second button takes a parameter. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the child component, second element of menuItems has an onClick property which is not a function but the returned value of the function.

Notice the difference closely:

```
menuItems: [
      {
        label: 'Action 1',
        onClick : this.action1 // assigning a function
      },
      {
        label: 'Action 2',
        onClick : this.action2('two') // assigning a value
        // because of invocation of the function, 
        // which essentially returns undefined.
      }
    ]
```

`undefined` is returned because the function:

```
action2: function (word) {
  console.log('--action 2--', word)
}
```

returns nothing.
and hence:

> Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the argument `two` to the function if that is how you intend to use it like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gmazhsw/).

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `this.action2.bind(null, 'two')` in that fiddle (or whatever `this` you intend).

Comment: @BertEvans Oh sorry, and `this.action2.bind(this, 'two')` might be a better choice?

Comment: The first argument to `bind` is what `this` will be inside the bound function. You're saying `this` should be `two`.

Comment: It depends on what `this` is required (what you want `this` to refer to).

Comment: @BertEvans True, but in this case that function was passed down as props, currently there are only console statements but it is likely that `this` gets used?

Comment: If `this` will not be used in the function, then `bind(null, ...)` is acceptable. See the "Partially applied functions" section of the MDN documentation you linked.